# GPS location once

Tags: android, dialog, gps, location, progress

I have an app that finds the users location (loading in a progress dialog) using GPS or network signal , when it finds it's location, the coordinates are written in a text view . If the GPS doesn't find a location in 40 sec or the user clicks on the cancel button , then the dialog closes. The problem is that if I click to cancel the dialog , it doesn't dismiss. However, if I click again, it dismisses. Why do I have to click twice ?!? Below is the source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LocationControl locationControlTask;
private boolean hasLocation = false;
LocationHelper locHelper;
protected Location currentLocation;
private TextView myText;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);

    locHelper = new LocationHelper();
    locHelper.getLocation(MainActivity.this, locationResult);
    locationControlTask = new LocationControl();
    locationControlTask.execute(this);


}

protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    // ....

    new LocationControl().execute(this);
}

private class LocationControl extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>
{
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Tap to cancel");
        this.dialog.setTitle("Searching");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(true);  
        this.dialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(which == Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dialog canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        this.dialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params)
    {
        //Wait 40 seconds to see if we can get a location from either network or GPS, otherwise stop
        Long t = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        while (!hasLocation && Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - t < 40000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused)
    {
        if(this.dialog.isShowing())
        {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (currentLocation != null)
        {
            //useLocation();
            String text = "lat:"+currentLocation.getLatitude()+" long:"+currentLocation.getLongitude();
            myText.setText(text);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "location could not be found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Couldn't find location, do something like show an alert dialog
        }
    }
}

public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult()
{
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(final Location location)
    {
        currentLocation = new Location(location);
        hasLocation = true;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    locHelper.stopLocationUpdates();
    locationControlTask.cancel(true);
    super.onStop();
} 
}
```

The location helper:

```
public class LocationHelper
{
LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gpsEnabled = false;
boolean networkEnabled = false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{       
    locationResult = result;

    if(locationManager == null)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
        //exceptions thrown if provider not enabled
        try
        {
            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
        try
        {
            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        //dont start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gpsEnabled && !networkEnabled)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(gpsEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        }
        if(networkEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        }


        //GetLastLocation();
        return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extra) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);

    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extra) {}

};

private void GetLastLocation()
{
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

        Location gpsLocation = null;
        Location networkLocation = null;

        if(gpsEnabled)
        {   //if()
            gpsLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        }
        if(networkEnabled)
        {
            networkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

        //if there are both values use the latest one
        if(gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null)
        {
            if(gpsLocation.getTime() > networkLocation.getTime())
            {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gpsLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                locationResult.gotLocation(networkLocation);
            }

            return;
        }

        if(gpsLocation != null)
        {
            locationResult.gotLocation(gpsLocation);
            return;
        }

        if(networkLocation != null)
        {
            locationResult.gotLocation(networkLocation);
            return;
        }

        //locationResult.gotLocation(null);
}

public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
}


public static abstract class LocationResult
{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
}
```

the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/mytext"  
      android:textSize="15dip"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Main activity"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

and these 2 permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I would appreciate it if anyone would take a look at the bug.

Comment: please indent your code, and mark the xml part as code, so the question will be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't do an in-depth analysis of your code, but you are starting the aysnc task in both onCreate and onStart. Remove it from one of those, because I suspect you simply have one dialog on top of the other.

Comment: thanks, you we're right, I opened the dialog twice. I deleted it from onCreate(), but does this mean that whenever the app goes into background or is paused, and after a while if the user goes back to the app again then the onStart() is called or should I implement onResume?

Comment: I'm not sure why your dialog exists, so it is a little difficult to answer that question. If the dialog was shown before the activity was left, (and the activity isn't killed), it should still be showing when you get back (without doing anything). If the activity is killed, then any function you have the open code in will show it again (create, start or resume). The trick is making sure the dialog isn't re-shown (if the user closed it before leaving your app) after a situation requiring your activity instance to be killed.